# How to install Polymer core elements

Tags: polymer, bower

Being new to front-end dev I have problem understanding what to choose when installing Polymer.  I installed Polymer using bower as per instruction

```
bower install --save Polymer/polymer#^1.0.0
```

When trying to install core-elements,

```
bower install --save Polymer/core-elements
```

I was presented with choices and I don't understand what to choose.

```
Unable to find a suitable version for webcomponentsjs, please choose one:
    1) webcomponentsjs#^0.6.0 which resolved to 0.6.3 and is required by polymer#0.5.6
    2) webcomponentsjs#^0.7.2 which resolved to 0.7.12 and is required by polymer#1.1.2
    3) webcomponentsjs#* which resolved to 0.7.12 and is required by core-component-page#0.5.6
```

Would appreciate some directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core-elements are deprecated. Most of them are now iron-elements while some are moved to paper elements.

`bower install PolymerElements/iron-elements`

`bower install PolymerElements/paper-elements`

Answer (score 0):

In general, just be sure that you are using **1.x** compatible components as this will not cause compatibility issues.